# getting STATE_DISCONNECTED while connecting using bluetooth smart

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to create a advertiser on Android L and my other android device is scanning that device and trying to make a connection with it.

but every time i call `connectGatt` i am getting `BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED` in gatt callback.

**this is how i have created the advertisement**

```
    // advertisement settings
   AdvertiseSettings.Builder builderSetting= new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
   builderSetting.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED);
   builderSetting.setConnectable(true);
   builderSetting.setTimeout(0);
   builderSetting.setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH);

    //advertisement data
    AdvertiseData.Builder builderData = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    builderData.addServiceUuid(new
                 ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")));

 byte mServiceData[] =
  { (byte)0xff, (byte)0xfe, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x04 };

   // i tried with addding service data 
   builderData.addServiceData(new
                 ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")), mServiceData);

   //start advertising
    mBTAdvertiser.startAdvertising(
      builderSetting.build(), 
      builderData.build(), mAdvCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't comment yet ill try to make it an answer.

In your example i only see the Advertising enabled. However to offer GATT services, you also need to create a GATT-server which handles the requests.

Check out the documentation to [BluetoothManager.openGattServer(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#openGattServer%28android.content.Context,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServerCallback%29).

Good luck!